# PHP foreach not working with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, loops, foreach

Please note that I am using Wordpress's default `$wpdb` object that you can use to make query to wordpress database.

```
global $wpdb;

$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `wpdp_wpforms_entries` WHERE `fields` LIKE '%unmatched%'", OBJECT );

foreach($results as $value) {
    print $value;
}
```

The error I get is:

```
Catchable fatal error : Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string.
```

SQL is correct because I tested it separately and it worked and fetched the following data:-

[image]

So then what is the problem?

Comment: It's an object not variable. check print_r($value);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print()` is for strings. http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php

`print_r()` is for all variables. http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

`$wpdb->get_results()` will most likely return an array of objects so in your case `$value` will contain an object.

**Try this:**

```
global $wpdb;

$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `wpdp_wpforms_entries` WHERE `fields` LIKE '%unmatched%'", OBJECT );

foreach($results as $value) {
    echo '<pre>'
    print_r($value);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must do this to access the results:

```
foreach($results as $value) {
    print $value->entry_id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

while you looping array of objects you get each object in the loop; you can't pass object as string to print function. 
try using `print_r()` method.